# Find last commit by Author

Tags: git, groovy, jgit

I want to check the author last commit, if it will be John, remove that file. I got error `expecting ')', found 'git'` and don't have idea what's wrong.

```
@Grapes(
@Grab(group='org.eclipse.jgit', module='org.eclipse.jgit', version='4.8.0.201706111038-r'))


import groovy.io.FileType
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.*
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.*
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.*


def changelogPath = "C:\\test" // value from branch
def packID = "test" // value from branch
def badAuthor = 'John'
String folderPath = "$changelogPath"+ "\\" + "$PackID" // Path to file Windows environment, if it will be Unix, change \\ -> //

def authorEqual(String packID, String changelogPath, String badAuthor) {

Git git = Git.open(new File("."))
PersonIdent aAuthort = commit.getAuthorIdent()
    try {
        RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git) 
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId()); 
            if(commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen().equals(aAuthor == BadAuthor)
                git.rm().call() <-- HERE
    }
}

authorEqual()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing `)` at the end of the `if`:

```
if (commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen().equals(aAuthor == BadAuthor))
    // This was missing ------------------------------------------^
    git.rm().call()
```

Comment: Dzizas, Thanks ! :)